# Recognizing the type of a container and copying it in C++

Tags: c++, generics, iterator, containers

My problem at hand is that I am working on an optimized bottom-up (iterative) merge sort. In order to save some computation, I need a buffer that is of the same length as the input range. My aim is that my implementation can sort not just arrays, but arbitrary containers also (`std::vector`, `std::array`, or even `std::list` if need be).

So, **my main question is**:
Using generics, how can I copy not just the content passed to the sort, but copy the structure that was passed to it. Of course, I don't want to explicitly deal with the container types, but rather be able to replicate the data and the data structure holding the data.

**Note**: My aim, also, is to come up with the implementation that can accept any input `std::stable_sort` can.

**Note 2**: So basically, given

```
template<class _RandomAccessIterator>
void sort(_RandomAccessIterator first, _RandomAccessIterator last) {
    Container<...> buffer = ...;
}
```

I want the `Container` to be of the same container type as `first` and `last` are computed from; is this possible in the first place?

(Don't ask me why I want to do it that way; the reason is good.)

Comment: Do you want `std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type` ?

Comment: Tried it already. No luck. :(

Comment: "generics" is a Java/C# word. In C++, it's "templates". They are much more powerful than generics, too.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I heard metaprogramming facilities in C++ are Turing-complete; is it so?

Comment: The standard library algorithms like `std::sort` work not with containers but with iterator ranges. This is not an accident. It would be wise to emulate this design choice. Of course if you want to go through some intellectual adventures before arriving at the same design decision it's totally your choice. If you need a temporary container, use one that is good for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the containers as function argument and then copy it with their `operator=`:

```
template <class Container>
void sort (Container &c) {
    auto copy = c; // Copied the container
    //
}
```

If you also want to handle C-arrays, just add an overload for them:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N >
void sort(T (&arr)[N]);
```

Comment: @Jarod42 So? A C-array is not a container. And if you want to handle them, just add an overload.

Comment: Well, the OP says *"My aim is that my implementation can sort not just arrays, but arbitrary containers also"*.